# How do I read what's in a binary tree in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, recursion, pattern-matching

I have the following type:

```
data Tree = Branch (Tree) (Tree) | Leaf Int deriving(Show)
```

now I want to create a function that gives the highest value leaf in the tree. But I am stuck, because I don't know how to get the two following trees of a given tree.

For example I have a tree a that looks like this: `let a = Branch (Leaf 10) (Leaf 2)`

How do I read the Leaf with value `10` in another function?

Comment: Maybe you should try first with the maximum of a plain list instead of a tree. It is the same approach, known as *pattern matching* together with recursion. Both data structures have exactly two constructors. See function `sum'` here in [LYAH](http://learnyouahaskell.com/syntax-in-functions) for example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A typical skeleton looks like this:

```
maxTree :: Tree -> Int
maxTree (Branch x y) = {- TODO -}
maxTree (Leaf n) = {- TODO -}
```

Answer (score 6):

When dealing with recursion, you need to keep in mind a base case.

For:

```
data Tree = Branch (Tree) (Tree) | Leaf Int deriving(Show)
```

Your base case is `Leaf Int`. The maximum value of a leaf is... the value held by that leaf.

```
maxTree :: Tree -> Int
maxTree (Leaf n) = n
```

Now, how do you deal with a `Branch`? What *is* a `Branch`? It's basically two more `Tree`s.

Consider a very simple `Tree`:

```
   Branch
    /  \
   /    \
  /      \
Leaf 1   Leaf 4
```

The max value is obviously `4`. Why? Because the `maxTree` computation on the right branch was bigger than the `maxTree` calculation on the left branch.

Consider a more complex `Tree`:

```
   Branch
    /  \
   /    \
  /      \
Leaf 1   Branch
          / \
         /   \
        /     \
     Branch   Leaf 8
      / \
     /   \
    /     \
  Leaf 3  Leaf 9
```

The answer is obviously `9`. How do we know this? Well, `maxTree` tells us the maximum value of `Leaf 1` is `1`. Each `Branch`'s max value is computed by figuring out the maximum value of the left and right branches. If we call maxTree recursively on each `Branch` eventually we compare `3` to `9`. Clearly `9` is bigger. Now we're comparing `9` to `8`. `9` is again bigger. And then `9` to `1`, and `9` wins out again.

Now you just need to translate that into *code*.

```
maxTree :: Tree -> Int
maxTree (Leaf n) = n
maxTree (Branch left right) = ...
```